Log-convexity of a generalisation of weigthed-Lp norms
Log-convexity of weigted Lp norms Let the weighted norm of a positive vector $q\in \mathrm R_+^d$ with weights $a\in \mathrm R_+^d$, be defined as
$${||q||}_{(p,a)} = (\sum_i a_i q_i^{p})^{1/p}$$
Then a classic result in interpolation theory/Solobev spaces states that the following function is convex on $p\geq 1$
$$ \frac{1}{p} \mapsto log||q||_{(p,a)}.$$
Generalisation Is this true for the following extension ? Let $A$ be a positive hermitian matrix, then
$$ \frac{1}{p} \mapsto log||A^{1/p} q||_p$$
is convex, where $A^{1/p}$ is the non-integer power of a matrix. We recover the result above when $A$ is diagonal.
I have some numerical evidence for this, but don't know how to prove it. I feel that, if true, the result should be probable from Hadamard's tree-line theorem.
Application
Many thanks for your help !
